# Invalid character in name error Fortran 77

Tags: fortran

[enter image description here][enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbi1e.png)Here is my code below:

```
            BZANGL=BZRANG(IM)

D                  TYPE *, 'BZANGL=',BZANGL

                BANGLE=BZANGL/RDN
```

Here is my error. Can someone help my understand?

```
MIAHCODE.f:51:21:
D              TYPE * , 'BZANGL=',BZANGL !the D is for -xl[d] debug fortran77
                     1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? This does not look like any Fortran construct I've seen before. I don't know what the `D` in the first column means. It's neither a `C` or a `!` which would mean that that's a comment), nor is it a label (they have to be numeric). If it was left out, I'd suspect that the `TYPE` would need to be `PRINT`, because `PRINT *, 'BZANGL=', BZANGL` is a valid statement, but the one in your question is not. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: This is very peculiar. If the D is for some non-standard debugging compiler option of yesteryear, I would comment this line and any other line with a D in the first column assuming you were given this old, working code. Did you add the comment after the ! for our benefit? Fortran 77 does not recognize that either.

Comment: FWIW some compilers do (or did) recognize both the `d` and the `!` conventions..here you see both are labeled as nonstandard https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007332024/index.html Of course the `!` was later adopted as standard.

Comment: ...same docs document the nonstandard `TYPE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chw21 mentioned, the word 'TYPE' is not a fortran statement. To print the values you desire you can use 'PRINT' or 'WRITE'. Also, as mentioned in the comment above, a D in column 1 signifies nothing. A C in column 1 means the line is a comment.

Comment: As mentioned in one of the linked questions, a `D` in the first column _does_ signify something.